# single sign on for two Umbraco sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, umbraco, single-sign-on

I have two Umbraco installes running on the same machine on EC2.
I would like to allow users of one site to create accounts on the other using their membership to the first, i.e. something like "Login in with Facebook". In my case "Log in to Y with your account on X".

I am currently thinking of two ways to do this:

1. Through a shared DB - Where I redirect from one site to an ASPX on another, do the authentication (if needed), save needed data in the shared DB and redirect back to the first site. It will work, but I don't like it because it just seems ugly!
2. Create a web service on the loopback (10.0.0.127) and use it to send authentication information one way, and the info needed to create the new account back.

Both will work, IMO, but I think there may be a more Umbraco way of doing this, or maybe a more standards based method at least.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are using members or users.

If you are using members and you can **securely** get the email from the other session, you can auto login by

```
Member member = Member.GetMemberFromEmail(<email address>);
Member.AddMemberToCache(member);
```

AddMemberToCache(member) will perform the login on the server side and create the members membership authentication cookie on the client machine.

and then check if the login worked with:

```
if (umbraco.library.IsLoggedIn())
{
...
}
```

If you are sharing a database the GetMemberFromEmail method will get the right member as it internally goes to the database:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed reply! I was looking for more of the how than the "What to do when". I know how to authenticate a member and get the member object by email. I can implement this in any of the methods I stated. Also, the machine key is shared (same machine), so theoretically, I could access one session from both applications (although not recommended, since session is not thread-safe).